# Select the next N elements of an IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Say you've got some IEnumerable called S of length N. I would like to select all continuous subsequences of length n <= N from S.

If S were, say, a string, this'd be pretty easy. There are (S.Length - n + 1) subsequences of length n. For example, "abcdefg" is length (7), so that means it has (5) substrings of length (3): "abc", "bcd", "cde", "def", "efg".

But S could be any IEnumerable, so this route isn't open. How do I use extension methods to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# has a library function called Seq.windowed for this.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/FSharp.Core/Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Seq.html

```
// windowed : int -> seq<'a> -> seq<array<'a>>
let windowed n (s: seq<_>) =    
    if n <= 0 then Helpers.invalid_arg2 "n" "the window size must be positive"
    { let arr = Array.zero_create n 
      let r = ref (n-1)
      let i = ref 0 
      use e = s.GetEnumerator() 
      while e.MoveNext() do 
          do arr.[!i] <- e.Current
          do i := (!i + 1) % n 
          if !r = 0 then 
              yield Array.init n (fun j -> arr.[(!i+j) % n])
          else 
              do r := (!r - 1) }
```

Comment: Awesome! This is pretty close to what I want. I'll see if I can translate this to C#.

Comment: That is WAY more complicated than necessary. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12238627/184528

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can use LINQ to solve this problem, e.g.

```
var subList = list.Skip(x).Take(y);
```

where list is an `IEnumerable`

Comment: I didn't actually try this, but doesn't that only return the first y elements after the first x elements? We'd need to do the Skip several times. Remember, we need *all* continuous subsequences, not just one of them! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Select extension that provides the index to create an object containing the index and value, then divide the index with the length to place them into groups:

```
var x = values.Select((n, i) => new { Index = i, Value = n }).GroupBy(a => a.Index / 3);
```

Comment: That's not quite right. You're really just splitting them up into groups of size N, not producing the individual subsequences. "abcde" with N = 3 should yield "abc", "bcd"< "cde", for example. But your method yields "abc", "de".

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ContiguousSubseqences<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T,bool> constraint)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (T t in seq)
    {
        if (constraint(t))
            yield return seq.Skip(i).TakeWhile(constraint);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new extension method to do what you want in C#

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Subseqs<T>(this IEnumerable<T> xs, int n) 
{
  var cnt = xs.Count() - n;  
  Enumerable.Range(0, cnt < 0 ? 0 : cnt).Select(i => xs.Skip(i).Take(n));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers.

Here is a small example.

```
    private static void RunTakeSkipExample()
    {
        int takeSize = 10; /* set takeSize to 10 */

        /* create 25 exceptions, so 25 / 10 .. means 3 "takes" with sizes of 10, 10 and 5 */
        ICollection<ArithmeticException> allArithExceptions = new List<ArithmeticException>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++)
        {
            allArithExceptions.Add(new ArithmeticException(Convert.ToString(i)));
        }

        int counter = 0;
        IEnumerable<ArithmeticException> currentTakeArithExceptions = allArithExceptions.Skip(0).Take(takeSize);
        while (currentTakeArithExceptions.Any())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Taking!  TakeSize={0}. Counter={1}. Count={2}.", takeSize, (counter + 1), currentTakeArithExceptions.Count());

            foreach (ArithmeticException ae in currentTakeArithExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ae.Message);
            }

            currentTakeArithExceptions = allArithExceptions.Skip(++counter * takeSize).Take(takeSize);
        }

    }
```

The output:

```
Taking!  TakeSize=10. Counter=1. Count=10.
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Taking!  TakeSize=10. Counter=2. Count=10.
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
Taking!  TakeSize=10. Counter=3. Count=5.
21
22
23
24
25
```

You can see by the .Message to each exception to verify each distinct exception was "taken".

And now, a movie quote!

> But what I do have are a very particular set of skills; skills I have
>   acquired over a very long career. Skills that make me a nightmare for
>   people like you.